# String after appending Char changning its size

Tags: c++

I want to test what if string append char's size, and below is the outcome.

I know that the string end with the null character, but why the outcome is like that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string a = "" + 'a';    //3
    string b = "" + '1';    //2
    string c = "a" + 'a';   //2
    string d = "1" + '1';   //3
    string e = "\0" + 'a';  //20
    string f = "\0" + '1';  //1
    string g = "a" + '\0';  //1
    string h = "1" + '\0';  //1
    string i = "" + '\0';   //0
    string j = "" + '\0';   //0
    cout << a.size() << endl;
    cout << b.size() << endl;
    cout << c.size() << endl;
    cout << d.size() << endl;
    cout << e.size() << endl;
    cout << f.size() << endl;
    cout << g.size() << endl;
    cout << h.size() << endl;
    cout << i.size() << endl;
    cout << j.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not doing what you think.

String literals decay to `const char *`, and `char` is an integer type. If you try to sum them, the compiler finds that the simplest way to make sense of that stuff is to convert `char`s to `int`s, so the result is performing pointer arithmetic over the string literals - e.g. `""+'a'` goes to the 97th character in memory after the beginning of the string literal `""` (if `'a'` is represented by 97 on your platform).

This results in garbage being passed to the `string` constructor, which will store inside the `string` being constructed whatever it finds at these locations of memory until it founds a `\0` terminator. Hence the "strange" results you get (which aren't reproducible, since the exact memory layout of the string table depends from the compiler).

Of course all this is undefined behavior as far as the standard is concerned (you are accessing `char` arrays outside their bounds, apart from the cases where you add `\0`).

To make your code do what you mean, at least one of the operands must be of type `string`:

```
string c = string("a") + 'a';
```

or

```
string c = "a" + string("a");
```

so the compiler will see the relevant overloads of `operator+` that involve `std::string`.

Comment: Why string("a") + '\0' size is 2// I think it should be 1,,,,
    string("\0") + 'a' size is 1//I think it should be 0,,,,
    string("") + '\0' size is 1//I think it should be 0,,,,,
String'size should not count the null character?

Comment: `std::string` is a *counted string*, i.e. its length is stored in a separate field, and the `\0` character does not act as a string delimiter - it's a normal character like any other one. Its presence inside the string does not change the string length.

Answer (score 1):

Most of your initializers have undefined behaviour. Consider, for example:

```
string a = "" + 'a';
```

You are adding a `char` to a `char` pointer. This advances the pointer by the ASCII value of the char, and uses the resulting (undefined) C string to initialize `a`.

To fix, change the above to:

```
string a = string("") + 'a';
```